# grep part of dataframe and use as title in plot

Tags: r, regex, plot

how do I get the name of a dataframe say

```
mydf.mtcars<-mtcars
```

and grep everything after the `.` i.e. `mtcars` and then use this as the title in a plot?

It would be the equivalent of doing

```
plot(mydf.mtcars,main="mydf")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> gsub("\\..*","",deparse(substitute(mydf.mtcars)))
[1] "mydf"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `deparse` and `substitute` to get the name of the data.frame. Then use some regular expression to remove the extrat part in the name.

For example :

```
sub('(.*)[.].*','\\1',deparse(substitute(mydf.mtcars)))
[1] "mydf"
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with both prior answers, but would wrap it in a function:

```
plotname <- function(d) {titl <- deparse(substitute(d)); 
                         plot(d, main=sub("[.].+$", "", titl) )}
plotname(mydf.mtcars)
```